# Probability of observing all cards?

Tags: probability, sampling, combinatorics, games

I have a stack of $n$ distinct cards. I randomly draw $N$ cards from the stack with replacement. Assume that $N \ge n$.

What is the probability that I observe all cards at least once?

**I got this far:**

The probability that the multiplicities of the states in the sample are $m_1, \dots, m_n$ is:

$$\frac{1}{n^{N}}\frac{N!}{m_1! \dots m_n!}$$

Therefore, the probability we want is found by evaluating the sum:

$$\frac{1}{n^{N}}\sum_{\begin{subarray}{c}
m_{1}+\dots+m_{n}=N\\
m_{k}\ge1
\end{subarray}}\frac{N!}{m_{1}!\dots m_{n}!}$$

However, I'm stuck since I'm not sure how to evaluate this. I tried a change of variables $r_k = m_k - 1$, but this messes the factorials in the denominator.

**Update:** I found this paper, which contains a solution:

> Kullback, Solomon. 1937. “On Certain Distributions Derived From the
>   Multinomial Distribution.” The Annals of Mathematical Statistics 8(3):
>   127–44. http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aoms/1177732409.

Comment: Is it a homework?

Comment: @Tim No, it isin't.

Comment: you may want to take a look at the multinomial distribution.

Comment: @EliKa See edit.

Comment: @Tim When you asked if it was homework, it's because you thought it was trivial? Maybe I'm missing something...

Comment: @becko I asked because of our policy on [self-study questions](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info)

Comment: How can N be >= n

Comment: @Paparazzi Because I am drawing with replacement.

Comment: For more information, please search our site for the [Coupon](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=coupon) Collector problem.